# Remove the intermediate option value for filtering?

Tags: f#

The following code returns `T seq`. The option value `c''` introduced is solely for the filtering and the function needs to get `c''.Value` for return value.

Is it another way to write it so there is no need to create a intermediate option value and two maps?

```
type T = { A: string; B: string; C: DateTime } // Maybe more fields
let f x =
  x
  |> Seq.map(fun y -> 
    let a = ...
    let b = ....
    let c' = .... // Some complex code
    let c'' = match c' with DateTimeExact "d" c -> Some c | _ -> None
    a, b, c''
  |> Seq.filter(fun (_, _, c'') -> match c'' with | None -> false | _ -> true
  |> Seq.map(fun (a, b, c'') -> { A = a; B = b; C = c''.Value }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Seq.choose` will do what you want.

It allows you to apply a map function from `'t -> 'u option` and filters out the elements that return `None`

Answer (score 1):

I would probably use a sequence computation expression:

```
let f xs = seq {
  for x in xs do
      let a = ...
      let b = ....
      let c' = .... // Some complex code
      match c' with 
        | DateTimeExact "d" c -> 
            yield { A = a; B = b; C = c }
        | _ -> 
            ()
}
```